# Can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, integer

I have written the following code snippet:

```
origilist = [6, 252, 13, 10]
decilist = list(xrange(256))


def yielding(decilist, origilist):
    half_origi = (len(origilist)/2)
    for n in decilist:
        yield origilist[:half_origi] + n + origilist[half_origi:]


for item in yielding(decilist, origilist):
    print item
```

when I run the code I get:

```
    yield origilist[:half_origi] + n + origilist[half_origi:]
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Is there anyway of joining an integer to another list, in a specific index?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: `append`, `[]+[]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only concat lists and `n` is the item in your list, not list. If you want to concat it with lists, you need to use [n], which is basically creating a list of one item.

In general, you can use `+` also for strings, but *every* item you want to concat needs to be string then. So if you have two lists and want to add any item to them, you need to convert that item to list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yield origilist[:half_origi] + [n] + origilist[half_origi:]
```

(`[n]` is a list with one element that can be concatenated to other lists).